# linking libaries and specifying path in makefile

Tags: c

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Linking apache libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2102821/linking-apache-libraries)

gcc 4.4.2 c89

I am trying to link some headers and libraries in my header file. But for some reason my program doesn't seem to link.

I have in my directory src/include/apr src/libs

I have compiled the libraries and placed them in my libs and I have put the headers in the include directory.

My executable is in the src directory.

In my makefile I have specified this:

```
LIBS_PATH -L./lib
INC_PATH -I./include

LIBS = -libapr-1
```

So the current directory to where the executable is executed from.

In my lib folder I have the following library called:

```
libapr-1.so
```

And in my include/apr folder I have the following header file:

```
apr.h
```

The program is getting the header files. But I don't think it is linking the library as I don't get any errors saying that it can't find the header file.

In the file where I include the header I have done this

```
#include <apr/apr.h>
```

I do get this following error message:

```
In file included from include/apr.h:17,                
./include/apr/apr.h:285: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘apr_int32_t’
```

Many thanks for any suggestions and advice,

EDIT:

```
LIBS_PATH -L./lib
INC_PATH -I./include

LIBS = -lapr
```

Error:
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lapr

Makefile:

```
OBJECT_FILES = dlg_fsm.o 

CFLAGS = -ggdb -Wall 

FLATFORM = -DLINUX

CC = gcc

LIBS_PATH = -L./lib
INC_PATH = -I./include

LIBS = -lapr

dlg: $(OBJECT_FILES)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(LDFLAGS) $(OBJECT_FILES) $(FLATFORM) $(INC_PATH) $(LIBS_PATH) $(LIBS) -o dlg
```

Comment: Do you get any prior error messages about missing header files?

Comment: You've got some confusing file names: include/apr.h and include/apr/apr.h - I wonder if there is some confusion going on? Maybe the header guards are getting confused?

Comment: Are you building your library from the directory in which you downloaded and compiled apr?  You should install apr and then use the installed files.  It could be that you have an older version of apr already installed, and the wrong header files are being included.

Comment: @robUK: Do you have libapr installed?  How are you linking in your makefile?  Try `LIBS="-L./lib -lapr-1"`, or `LIBS="-L./lib -lapr"`.

Comment: What I did, and maybe this is my mistake. But I didn't install the apr. I just copied the library to my /src/lib folder and copied the headers to my src/include/apr folder. I was thinking just having the libraries and the headers in those folders. I should be able to link. However, I am not sure why I am getting the "error: /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lapr. The library is in my src/lib folder and nowhere else. Thanks for your support.

Comment: I have edited and posted my makefile. Thanks.

Comment: Is it libapr.so or libapr-1.so?

Comment: Then you need to change your Makefile.

Comment: I have added another question and closed this one. I felt by editing my answer too much would cause confusion. New question is called linking apache libraries. There I have installed and tried to link with a simple makefile and source file.

Answer (score 2):

This has nothing to do with libraries, and may have nothing to do with paths. The compiler thinks there is a syntax error at the line indicated - please post that line, and the ones surrounding it, using copy and paste.

Answer (score 1):

Once you've fixed the syntax error in your code, you'll want to change LIBS to contain `-lapr-1`, since the linker adds the "lib" prefix itself.

Comment: Yes. I have corrected that. The library is called libapr-1.so. So in my makefile I have called it -lapr-1.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely the compiler doesn't know what `apr_int32_t` means, whereas it should.  You should post line 285 of `apr.h`.

*Edit*: I think when you say:

> And in my `include/apr` folder I have the following header file: `apr.h`

that might be what's wrong.  You should not have an `apr.h` file in your local directory—it's a file from APR.  So, try renaming the file `include/apr/apr.h` to something else (unless by `include/apr` you meant your system include directory).

*Edit 2*:

```
LIBS_PATH -L./lib
INC_PATH -I./include
```

From the above, looks like you're in the `apr` source directory.  Please install `apr` by typing `make install` in the `apr` directory, and then use the installed files in `/usr/include/apr` and `/usr/lib/libapr*` to build your program.  You should not have your local source and include directories in the `apr` directory.

Comment: I commented out the errors I was getting. However, now I compile I get the following error: /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lapr-1. I guess that its looking in the default path. However, is it possible to do link with my custom path i.e. LIBS_PATH -L.lib thanks.

Comment: Yes, linking like that should be possible, but try `-lapr` first?  So now you're saying that compilation worked without an errors?  What did you do?  Also, post your updates in your main post, not as reply here - makes it easier for others to follow this post.

Answer (score 1):

Either there is a syntax error in apr.h or probably apr.h expects something to be included before itself.

For example:

you write header file abc.h which uses strlen(...), but do not include string.h inside abc.h . If you want to include abc.h in file xxx.c, you have to include string.h in xxx.c before abc.h manually to make sure that abc.h has access to the declaration of strlen(...)