# Linking apache libraries

Tags: c

gcc 4.4.2

I have installed apache runtime portable. apr-1.3.9

```
./configure
make
make test
make install
```

Everything installed fine.

I have in my `/usr/local/apr/lib` all the libraries and the includes in the following `/usr/local/apr/include/apr-1`

I have a simple main.c program to test:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <apr.h>

int main(void)
{
    printf(" == Start of program ==\n");

    return 0;
}
```

And my makefile:

```
OBJECT_FILES = main.o

CC = gcc
CFLAGS = -Wall -g -D_LARGEFILE64_SOURCE

LIBS_PATH = -L/usr/local/apr/lib
INC_PATH = -I/usr/local/apr/include/apr-1

LIBS = -lapr-1

test_apr: $(OBJECT_FILES)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(OBJECT_FILES) $(LIBS_PATH) $(INC_PATH) $(LIBS) -o test_apr

main.o: main.c
    $(CC) -c $(CFLAGS) $(INC_PATH) $(LIBS_PATH) $(INC_PATH) main.c
```

However, when I try and compile I get the following error:

```
gcc -c -I/usr/local/apr/include/apr-1 -L/usr/local/apr/lib -I/usr/local/apr/include/apr-1 main.c    
In file included from main.c:3:
/usr/local/apr/include/apr-1/apr.h:285: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘apr_off_t’
make: *** [main.o] Error 1
make: Target `test_apr' not remade because of errors.
```

However, I don't understand this as the header file is called apr.h in the apr-1 folder and the libary I am linking with is called libapr-1.so

I know my paths are correct I have double check them. So can't understand why I can't link them.

Many thanks for any advice,

Comment: @rob: I (and others) spent a lot of time trying to find your problem few hours ago.  Now we're back to square one.

Comment: typedef off64_t apr_off_t; that is the line. However, I didn't think there would be any problem with the apr.h source code because that is part of the apache runtime.

Comment: @robUK: aha.  You need to let the compiler know you're compiling large file support.  apr.h source code is compilable, but only with the flags it is supposed to be compiled with, not anything you want.

Comment: I only have an old version of the APR installed, which doesn't have the type off64_t. You did not by chance install 64-bit version of the APR on a 32-bit machine (or vice versa)? Clutching at straws here...

Comment: I downloaded from this link: http://apr.apache.org/download.cgi apr-1.3.9.tar.gz. But after double checking I don't see anything about 32 bit or 64. It doesn't specify 32 or 64.

Comment: Well, it seems Alok has identified the problem. A pointer for the future - when people trying to solve your problems ask you to post the code, post the code! This could all have been sorted out hours ago if you had done so.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

My crystal ball tells me that you need to run add `-D_LARGEFILE64_SOURCE` to `CFLAGS`, or if you're on linux: the command `getconf LFS_CFLAGS` gives you an exact list of `CFLAGS` to add to your existing `CFLAGS` for large file support.

Finally, you should actually use `apr-1-config --cflags` to get a list of compiler flags if possible.

Comment: Looks like your crystal balls were right. Currently I am compiling on linux 32 bit. However, there is no way I was would have know about -D_LARGEFILE64_SOURCE to add to the CFLAGS. I guess that is just down to experience. The command LFS_CFLAGS did give me the list of flags to add. However, the apr-1-config --cflags just gave me -pthread. Is that correct?

Comment: @rob: Use both the output of getconf command and -pthread.  As Neil said, this problem should have been solved hours ago, trivially, if you had posted the code earlier when asked.  I think `apr-1-config --cppflags` might be the command to print the C preprocessor flags.  Try that too.

Comment: Thanks for help. This might seem like silly question. But do all libraries have -config command to run,so that you always know what to include in your make file?

Comment: @rob: it's not a formal standard, although many programs provide such `-config` command.  For some others, `pkg-config` works.  But it's highly dependent on the program which method to use, if any at all.

Answer (score 3):

This is a near dupe of your previous question, so I will give a near dupe of my previous answer - this is not a linker error. You need to pass the include path to the compiler, not the linker:

```
main.o: main.c
    $(CC) -c $(INC_PATH) main.c
```

Comment: At least this question is much better formed than the previous question.

Comment: Actually, I was making too many changes to that previous question. So decided to close it. Here I am started fresh by installing the apache runtime and making a simple source file and makefile. However, I am still getting errors after making the changes Neil suggested.